# Show different picklist value based on selected record type value in custom vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have a picklist with record type values and I need to show different fields based on selected value and also if there are any picklist we need to put values in that based on record type in a custom vf page.Not sure how to achieve this using apex?

Comment: If you use an `apex:inputField` and have the `RecordTypeId` set on the SObject I think that the relevant entries will show (but double check that).

Comment: could you please provide me a blog where I can get an idea of the same

Comment: Well it should (if I've got it right) just work. If the data has been queried make sure to include the RecordTypeId in the query and if it is a new object instance make sure to set the RecordTypeId up front.